# how to integrate 2-3 algorithms to encrypt large data fastly and securely insted using AES?

Tags: algorithm-design, symmetric

I am thinking to build an encryption algorithm which take less time when encrypt large data such as video,mp3 and which has security credential.

Comment: AES is **really** fast. On more recent x86 and x86-64 chips, you won't get anything faster, because they have AES built into the actual hardware. Is AES actually not fast enough in practice? Because until you test it, don't just assume it's slow.

Comment: Furthermore, no algorithm you build will be remotely as secure as AES (or, for that matter, remotely secure at all). Crypto design is **hard**. There are other primitives with reasonable acceptance that are faster than AES in software (Salsa20 comes to mind, although it doesn't beat AES on chips with AES-NI, which is most newer ones), but none quite as trusted as AES; however, you shouldn't be making your own, period.

Comment: Additionally, no modern cryptographic algorithm will perform differently based on what type of data it's operating on. Video, audio, text, and anything else is irrelevant, because modern ciphers operate on raw *bytes*.

Comment: What is your actual question here?

Comment: Voted to close – unclear what you’re asking. Maybe if you would add some more details…

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that is faster than AES, there are several options.

HOWEVER (and this is a big one) if [AES-NI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) instructions (hardware acceleration) are available to you, there is nothing that can come close. My computer is a few years old, and I get 3100MiB/s in CTR mode. That is 3 gigabytes every second. That is faster than the network interface, and faster than the fastest SATA SSD.

If you do not have AES hardware acceleration, [Twofish](https://www.schneier.com/twofish.html) can be substantially faster depending on the implementation used. It is 24% faster on one test, 440% faster in another. Certain programming languages cannot implement AES as efficiently as Twofish and other ciphers. [ChaCha](http://cr.yp.to/chacha.html) may also be up to several times faster than AES, and is a seekable stream cipher, making it suitable for accessing large files. SOSEMANUK and Rabbit stream ciphers are also faster than unaccelerated AES. Twofish and ChaCha would be the only ciphers that I would consider both at least as secure and noticeably faster than AES under certain conditions, that have a large enough block size, and have had enough cryptanalysis done in which to be confident of their security. Several other ciphers do exist which have good performance, but would not rate nearly as high.

AES does have the advantage of a very lightweight key schedule, so if you have to change keys often and encrypt small amounts of data, it may be faster anyway. Encrypting large data files excludes this advantage. AES is also [faster on 8-bit microcontrollers](https://www.emsec.rub.de/media/crypto/veroeffentlichungen/2011/01/29/lw_speed2007.pdf) than alternative lightweight ciphers, but has a larger code size than some of them. These other ciphers are designed to be as fast and compact as possible, but AES has a byte oriented design and still does very well.

[image: Performance on 4MHz 8-bit processor]

The other advantage AES will have is interoperability, since it is a standard and widely used. Every computer built in the last 15 years can run it, and new computers can do it quickly and securely. Even phones, video game consoles, and even some watches can run AES.

If you are looking to build a custom algorithm, and have it be as secure as AES but faster, and you need to ask this question, you will probably not succeed. Use AES or an algorithm with good security confidence by those who have studied them.